# Notepad++ go to definition

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way for Notepad++ to navigate to a definition? I'd like to give it a directory where my libraries are, search it and open the source/header file at the line of reference in a new tab. Much like NetBeans.

I've just installed [SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/), it's good but I can't get it to search anything else but the already opened files. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just do a manual search within the library folder for the function header.

Comment: It looks like neither SourceCookifier nor TagsJump works for the R language. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27):

In Notepad++, you can use TagsJump plugin to jump to a definition.
Install it by using PluginManager.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks. Also install TagsView to see the generated tags and have in-current-file navigation.

Comment: Is is possible to change the jump shortcut into "ctrl + left mouse click" ?

Comment: @Liran: Why would you like to do that. Notepad++ enables multi-edit by using ctrl + left click and this is an awesome feature. To answer to your question, the default shortcut mapped does not enable use of mouse actions unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

Simply drag and drop your top level source folder into the SourceCookifier window. Additionally pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> while dropping will speed up everything, since no tags are shown in the tree view then. Check out the short manual and start using session files.

Answer (score 9):

Just like ufo, I had better results with **Source Cookifier**.

After opening its side window

1. Go to "Cookie session mode"

[image: Cookie Session mode]

2. Drag & Drop your folders with source code to Source Cookifier window
3. Select the type of files you want to parse

[image: Select file type]

4. In Notepad++, put the cursor in the function/type you want to get definition of, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to jump to the definition. If there are several definitions, you can choose the file you want to open

[image: Select file]

5. You can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> to come back to the previous location

[image: Navigate Backward]

**Notes:**

- You can save and load the cookie sessions; moreover, Source Cookifier display the history of the latest sessions
- Opening the file of a saved session in Notepad++ will automatically switch SourceCookifier into cookie session mode and load this session
- Maintaining a keyboard modifier (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, or <kbd>ALT</kbd> - they are
  all similar) while drag-dropping the folder will fasten the parsing by only adding INCLUDES and not tags

[image: Drad&Drop with keyboard modifier]

Comment: I couldn't find a 64-bit version of the SourceCookifier plugin. Did you find one?

Comment: @LarsH Not available in 64-bit indeed. 3 choices: **A.** Wait for 64-bit version of the plugin, **B.** Install Notepad++ 32-bit, **C.** Use some more powerful tools (which is a better choice if you have complex code). **Visual Code** is a great free alternative.

Comment: I have the following problem using SourceCookifier: [click here to see details](https://sourceforge.net/p/sourcecookifier/discussion/1067263/thread/154f4bb7/#a5ac). Appreciate if someone could point me to a solution.

Comment: @tarekahf  I personally don't write Javascript and I don't use SourceCookifier much anymore. However, I can recommend (instead of Notepad++) using Visual Studio Code which is very nice for Javascript.